# R data.table lapply split by segment: expecting wrong data type

Tags: r, data.table, lapply

I am working on a medical data set.  Each patient has time-updated records across different rows.  For each patient, we want to compute the time of their first hospitalization, first heart attack, or death.  For those without any records during the time of the study, we'll return NA as a missing value.

This seems like a great opportunity to use R's data.table package, but I am getting a strange error.  Here is an example:

```
library(data.table)
dat <- data.table(id = c(1,1,2,2), begin = c(0, 20, 0, 50), 
                  hospital = c(1,0,0,1), heart.attack = c(0,0,0,1), 
                  death = c(0,1,0,1))
print(dat)

    id begin hospital heart.attack death
1:  1     0        1            0     0
2:  1    20        0            0     1
3:  2     0        0            0     0
4:  2    50        1            1     1
```

This function calculates the minimum time that an event occurred.  If no event occurred, return a missing value.

```
first.calc <- function(outcome, time){
        w <- which(as.logical(outcome) == TRUE)
        if(length(w) > 0){
            return(min(time[w]))
        }
        else{
           return(NA)
        }
}
```

Note: these variables are used because I'm actually writing a function to apply these techniques on multiple data sets with unknown names.

```
time.name = "begin"
id.name = "id"
outcome.names = c("hospital", "heart.attack", "death")

res <- dat[, lapply(X = .SD, FUN = "first.calc", 
             time = get(time.name)), 
             .SDcols = outcome.names, 
             by = id.name]

**Error in `[.data.table`(dat, , lapply(X = .SD, 
              FUN = "first.calc", time = get(time.name)),  : 
     Column 2 of result for group 2 is type 
     'double' but expecting type 'logical'. Column types must 
     be consistent for each group.**
```

Meanwhile, the function seems to work on a single patient or without subsetting:

```
dat[id == 1, lapply(X = .SD, FUN = "first.calc", 
                    time = get(time.name)), 
             .SDcols = outcome.names, 
              by = id.name]
    id hospital heart.attack death
1:  1        0           NA    20

dat[id == 2, lapply(X = .SD, FUN = "first.calc", 
                     time = get(time.name)), 
                     .SDcols = outcome.names, 
                     by = id.name]
    id hospital heart.attack death
1:  2       50           50    50

dat[, lapply(X = .SD, FUN = "first.calc", 
                      time = get(time.name)), 
            .SDcols = outcome.names]

         hospital heart.attack death
1:        0           50    20
```

So why is this error occurring when I use **by = id.name** on the full data set?

I have read through most of the Similar Questions.  There was not much information about this specific issue.  Sorry if this question is a duplicate.  Thanks for looking at it!

Comment: NA is of type logical. If you want numeric, use NA_real_. The error explains itself well: "Column types must be consistent for each group." With by= you have groups; without it. you don't...

Comment: Thanks Frank!  That solved the problem.